# how i can combine these two for loop to print a full triangle

Tags: python-2.7

I want to print a full triangle asterisk by combining these two half triangle.

```
for g in range (11,0,-1):
    print(g * ' ' + (11-g) * '*')

for i in range(11,0,-1):
    print ('*'*(11-i)+ ' '*i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python [format mini language](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#formatspec) provides a powerful mechanism for controlling how things are displayed

In particular you are looking for a triangle of `*` centered `^` and padded with a . The width of the triangle is `2n-1` for a triangle of size `n`, e.g. for `n=5`: the format spec would be `' ^9'`.
The number of `*` in each row is `2i-1 for i in 1..n`.

So putting this all together you get:

```
>>> n = 5
>>> for i in range(1, n+1):
...     print(format('*'*(2*i-1), ' ^'+str(2*n-1)))
    *    
   ***   
  *****  
 ******* 
*********
```

Or as a single expression (using variable substitution):

```
print('\n'.join('{: ^{width}}'.format('*'*(2*i-1), width=2*n-1) for i in range(1, n+1)))
```